# Global markup extensions in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to create a global reference for a markup extension in Xamarin Forms?

I'm using a markup extension to provide localization, and would like to register the namespace once, rather than in every view.

For example, here is a simple page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Views.Home"
             xmlns:i18n="clr-namespace:App.Globalization">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="{i18n:Translate Welcome}"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

What I want to do is not require every page to include the `xmlns:i18n` namespace, but include it globally.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** No. It's not possible, unless you switch your xmlns definitions. And also please note this is a XML limitation, not just XAML.

### How this works:

The only way to do this is through use of [`XmlnsDefinitionAttribute`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/XmlnsDefinitionAttribute.cs). XAML parsers (both compile-time, and run-time) look for these attributes on assemblies to glean the default global namespace declarations much like [following line in `AssemblyInfo` in Xamarin.Forms.Core](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs#L36).

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms", "Xamarin.Forms")]
```

You can find some of these parsing methods [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks/XmlTypeExtensions.cs#L25).

The above line coupled with this attribute

> xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"

that is included by default in your custom XAML pages/views, allow you to directly use controls like `ContentPage`, `StackLayout`, `Grid` etc. without having to specify the `Xamarin.Forms` namespace

Now, you can see both [`XmlnsDefinitionAttribute`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/XmlnsDefinitionAttribute.cs), and [XmlTypeExtensions](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks/XmlTypeExtensions.cs#L25) are marked as internal. So there is no easy way to get around it.

What you can try is switching your xmlns namespace definitions as following (please note I am sharing this just for illustration purpose only). This will allow you to not have to specify prefix for `TranslateExtension`.

```
<f:ContentPage xmlns="clr-namespace:App.Globalization" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleApp"
             xmlns:f="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             x:Class="SampleApp.MainPage">
    <f:ContentPage.Content>
        <f:StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <f:Label Text="{Translate Welcome}"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        </f:StackLayout>
    </f:ContentPage.Content>
</f:ContentPage>
```

Answer (score -1):

No. The same applies for C# code - can you declare using of some namespace globally? Of course not.